# What was the needle on the nose of Space Shuttle Enterprise for?

Tags: space-shuttle

[image: Photo of Space Shuttle Enterprise in flight, with the needle on the nose]

What is the purpose of the needle-like object on the nose?

[Why do experimental aircraft such as the X-35 have such long Pitot tubes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95710/why-do-experimental-aircraft-such-as-the-x-35-have-such-long-pitot-tubes) is related but not a duplicate; it does not actually say what the object is, because it doesn't mention the space shuttle. Just because some experimental aircraft have long pitot tubes on the nose doesn't mean that any needle-like object on the nose of an experimental aircraft is necessarily a pitot tube. Even if an object like this on an aircraft is always a pitot tube, that's not obvious to a non-expert, even after reading that question and its answers.

Comment: Actually, I think that indeed any needle-like object on the nose of an experimental aircraft **is** a pitot tube :)

Comment: The interesting aspect of the Enterprise having a Pitot tube is that it would not be expected unless you were aware that it was never designed to be flown in space.  Most people, I suspect, would assume the Enterprise was flown in space.

Comment: @U_flow that might be the case, and it might even be obvious to experts, but it isn't obvious to a non-expert, even after reading the linked question.

Comment: @Someone sorry, my comment was not meant to be an insult. But the more I think about it, the more I think it is actually true. These are always pitot tubes, or pitot tubes combined with Angle of attack and sideslip sensors.

Comment: I didn't think your comment was an insult; sorry if mine came across that way.

Comment: The "as duplicate of" question ***doesn't*** mention the space shuttle, but the answer to it discusses how "When test flying new aircraft long pitot tubes ... are used to ensure the probes are free of any interference the body of the aircraft may cause." So the question isn't identical, but the answer there applies here.  That understanding of "duplicate" avoids having a large number of questions, "why the long metal tube on the ___" for any number of various aircraft. While not the same verbatim question *text*, it's the same quandary, all with the same answer.

Comment: @RalphJ Can you maybe add [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51978/what-is-this-transport-aircraft-and-why-does-it-sometimes-cary-an-air-data-boom) as a second duplicate? It also discusses the **air data boom** (for An-225 and the Buran).

Comment: It is a duplicate now with @sophit 's edit to that question, so I retracted my reopen vote.

Comment: @Someone: hopefully that answer answers your question in a satisfactory way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this website](https://aerospaceweb.org/question/spacecraft/q0288.shtml):

> **Enterprise** was the first Space Shuttle built for NASA. Although officially classified as an Orbiter and given the designation OV-101 for Orbiter Vehicle 101, Enterprise was not actually capable of traveling in space. Enterprise had no rocket engines or thermal protection tiles and was **equipped with a pitot tube on the nose** that limited it to low speed atmospheric flights only. Enterprise was instead a prototype used to test the Orbiter's flight characteristics during landing. It performed a similar function as Russia's Analog Buran did in collecting information on how well the vehicle performed during approach and landing.

*(emphasis is mine)*

(*Short explanation*: A Pitot tube is used to measure and provide airspeed information.)

Comment: Someone: your last edit **significantly** modified this answer. That is not what editing other people's posts is for (see e.g. [edit posts privilege](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)).

Comment: @Bianfable: I think it conveyed all of the same information? I'm concerned that the quote might be copyright infringement; that's why I edited it.

Comment: @Someone I'm not a lawyer, but I'm fairly sure this falls under *fair use*. Feel free to ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) about it (or search there, someone might have already asked about it).

Comment: @Someone I appreciate your concern, but my understanding is the purpose of the "block quote" linked to the source is for proper attribution. The use of block quotes linked to the source is used everyday on ASE. I'm not sure what's different about the block quote (linked to the source) that I included in my answer.

Comment: @Bianfable it might be, but I would not expect a non-transformative direct copy to be fair use.

Comment: @757toga attribution means it's not plagiarism, but it doesn't necessarily avoid copyright infringement. It may make it more likely to be fair use, but it's far from a guarantee.

Comment: @Someone  Block quotes are used on ASE, with links to the source, for regulations, FCOMs, Wikipedia, books, technical data sheets, etc.  I can't image a purpose for linking a quote directly to the source and identifying it as a quote from the source as being problematic. Here is a link to a Stack Exchange Meta page discussing using [Block Quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306035/where-should-i-use-blockquotes). Anyway, I could be wrong, but a quote from a source linked directly to the source seems to be a staple on ASE. I'm always open to learning new things.